# Pandas Comparision of dataframe wherever zero in the one dataframe make zero on other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I wanted to put zero on on dataframe compare to other is there any way to do it please suggest me

Only zero I wanted replace from df1 to df2

df1

```
  name data1 data2 data3 data4            
  cm1   10     0    30     0              
  cm2    0    20     0    20         
  cm3    1     0    20    NaN
```

df2

```
 name  data1 data2 data3 data4  
 cm1     6    10    15    20
 cm2     9   NaN    20     3
 cm3     1   NaN    20    30
```

output
df2

```
name  data1 data2 data3 data4  
 cm1     6    0     15    0
 cm2     0   NaN     0    3
 cm3     1    0     20   30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check when your `df1` is `0`, and `fillna` using your `df2`:

```
df1[df1==0].fillna(df2)
```

prints:

```
  name  data1  data2  data3  data4
0  cm1    6.0    0.0   15.0    0.0
1  cm2    0.0    NaN    0.0    3.0
2  cm3    1.0    0.0   20.0   30.0
```

---

Note that this alignes on indices, so you might want to first set your `index` in both `df` to be 'name':

```
df1.set_index('name',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('name',inplace=True)

new_df2 = df1[df1==0].fillna(df2)

>>> new_df2
  name  data1  data2  data3  data4
0  cm1    6.0    0.0   15.0    0.0
1  cm2    0.0    NaN    0.0    3.0
2  cm3    1.0    0.0   20.0   30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find zeros in df1 using df1==0, index them in df2, and set the values to zero.

```
df2[df1==0]=0
```